# How can I get rid of the numbering of one section in the header?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, numbering

My last chapter is called "Anhang" and I wrote in LaTeX `\section*{Anhang}`. Then it doesn't have a numbering but for the heading I get `5.Anhang`. How can I get rid of the `5.` (the number is from the section before)?

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
  \pagestyle{headings}
  \def\eop{\hfill$\square$}
  \begin{document}

  \section*{Anhang}
  \sectionmark{Anhang}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Anhang}
  \end{document}
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
\section*{Anhang}
\renewcommand\thesection{\hspace{-1em}}
\sectionmark{Anhang}
```

However, using package `fancyhdr` and also the command `\appendix` makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I always use a custom \secstar because the changes can be done easily (like color, size, position etc.)  see below

```
\newcommand{\secstar}[1]{ 
\thispagestyle{fancy}\clearpage\phantomsection\vspace*0pt}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
\centerline{\bf\lsstyle }
\centerline{\huge \lsstyle \color{cyan} #1}
\vspace*{35pt}
}
```

and then

```
\subsecstar{Anhang}
```